# Open iPhone camera in a frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera, frame

I want to open iPhone camera in a frame. Actually I have a image in Heart shape. So I want to open camera in this image. So please can any one suggest me how I do this.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to use overlay in camera this is achived through Avfoundation the available example is SquareCam on apple's developers site

Answer (score 2):

Below are the steps for getting framed image with camera click:

1 Open a view which is containing cut image of heart shape frame.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height );
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

2 Call camera overlay below that cut heart shape image to use camera for snapping images.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = (sender == takePictureButton) ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController: picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

3 Click the image let the image view be there and enable snapped image editable.

4 Then take screen shot with heart shape image view to get your image as per your requirement.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIImagePickerController` has an `cameraOverlayView` property. I haven't tried it but I imagine you can add a `UImageView` as a subView of that, using an image with an alpha channel to mask the areas you don't want the camera to show through.

Why not give it a try and report back on how it works.

> cameraOverlayView
>
> The custom view to display on top of the default image picker
>   interface. @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *cameraOverlayView
>   Discussion
>
> You can use an overlay view to present a custom view hierarchy on top
>   of the default image picker interface. The image picker layers your
>   custom overlay view on top of the other image picker views and
>   positions it relative to the screen coordinates. If you have the
>   default camera controls set to be visible, incorporate transparency
>   into your view, or position it to avoid obscuring the underlying
>   content.